# UTF-8 characters are corrupted after being Parsed with GWT XMLParser

Tags: xml, parsing, gwt, utf-8

I just don't see through myself currently. This should be standard: I get an XML with some UTF-8 characters, which i want to parse.

Here is an example: 
    `<person><name>Nguyển Thị Ngân</name></person>`

When I parse this with GWTs XMLParser and print out the name node value, then the characters are corrupted:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><person><name>Nguyển Thị Ngân</name></person>";

Document doc= XMLParser.parse(xml);

NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++){
    System.out.println("XMLParser: " + list.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
System.out.println("System.out: " + xml);
```

The output is:

`XMLParser: Nguyá»n Thá» NgÃ¢n`

`System.out: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><person><name>Nguyển Thị Ngân</name></person>`

which I interpret, that it the character mess has nothing to do with the printing via System.out.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<?xml ?>`-decl? You're parsing a String, so it's already made of characters, not bytes, and thus encoding is not needed. It could be a browser bug. Also, does it happen in all browsers you tested it with, or only one of them?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the non-latin characters with their unicode escape codes? Double check that your development environment is saving the files as UTF-8.

Comment: @Thomas Broyer: the removal does not make any difference. So far I only ran the code as GWTTestCase. I will follow your advice and test it in different browsers in production mode. Will do that on Monday.

Comment: @chooban: I checked that, the file is UTf-8 encoded by default. I have no problems with JSON or any other i18n characters from properties files. that's why I am really lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is as described by Thomas Broyer. It can't be what chooban says because printing the raw XML works as expected. You could try to replace the unicodes with their XML escape codes:

```
StringBuilder xmlEscaped = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < xml.length(); i++) {
   char c = xml.charAt(i);
   if (c < 127) {
     xmlEscaped.append(c);
   } else {
     xmlEscaped.append("&#" + ((int) c) + ";");
   }
}
Document doc = XMLParser.parse(xmlEscaped.toString());
```

Comment: Stefan Haustein: Your code is giving me the result expected! Thanks a lot! 
I wonder, why is this not part of the XMLParser logic, as UTF-8 characters are so widley used. I would have expected it to work 'out-of-the-box'.

Comment: This will only work if the non-ASCII characters are not in an element or attribute name, right?